getting request error while hit linkedin post on url (https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts) api
We're having trouble getting the API to work. Getting response:-
{ message: 'Organization permissions must be used when using organization as author', status: 400 }
const postData = {
        author: `urn:li:organization:${process.env.LINKEDIN_ORGANIZATION_ID}`,
        commentary: req.body.text,
        visibility: "PUBLIC",
        distribution: {
          feedDistribution: "MAIN_FEED",
          targetEntities: [],
          thirdPartyDistributionChannels: [],
        },
        lifecycleState: "PUBLISHED",
        isReshareDisabledByAuthor: false,
      };

const config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "LinkedIn-Version": versionNumber,
        },
        data: postData,
      };

